# Removing all HTML inside XML

Tags: xml, xslt, solr, html-entities

I am trying to feed some XML into Apache Solr, but some of the XML contains some HTML formatting in the text which won't let me post to my solr server.  Obviously it would be nice to be able to preserve this information as my docs could then be pre-formatted before posting.  But I have not seen or am aware of if escaping will avoid solr's issue with the HTML.  My question is hot do I remove HTML from XML using XSLT?

For example:

```
What I have:

<field name="description"><h1>This is a description of a doc!</h1><p> This doc contains some information</p></field>

What I need:

<field name="description">This is a description of a doc! This doc contains some information.</field>
```

I want to have an intelligent fix, not a blacklist of particular tags to not scrub during the xsl translation.  This would be inefficient because if one decides to create a new doc with say  tag, the blacklist would not see this unless the programmer adds it manually.

I have tried converting the HTML tags to html entities (< and &gr; for < and > respectively), but this screws up things later down the line when I try to post this via HtmlPost via BasicNameValuePairs.  I don't want to use these entities.

Any ideas StackOverflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the element(s) that contain the HTML, you can match any of that elements descendants and do an apply-templates.

Example...

**XML Input**

```
<field name="description"><h1>This is a <b>description</b> of a doc!</h1><!--Here's a comment--><p> This doc contains some information</p></field>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()[ancestor::field and not(self::text())]">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<field name="description">This is a description of a doc! This doc contains some information</field>
```

Comment: But this would not get rid of HTML commenting such as <!-- Foo -->  So it isn't quite as intelligent as I would like.  You see?

Comment: @BenjaminNeigher - You could change the match to `node()[ancestor::field and not(self::text())]`.

Comment: @BenjaminNeigher - I updated my example to show comments also being removed.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! This will do